# not able to get the value WebDriver using java

Tags: java, html, knockout.js, selenium-webdriver

Please find the HTMl code

```
<input type="password" maxlength="20" id="txtRegPassword" data-bind="value: Password,   valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',qtipValMessage:Password" class="input-txt ErrorControl" data-orig-  title="" data-hasqtip="3" oldtitle="Password doesn't meet the Password Policy." title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
```

my requirement it get the oldtitle value ("Password doesn't meet the Password Policy)

following are my code(Java) but i'm getting null value

```
String Validationmessagepwd = driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("input#txtRegPassword")).getAttribute("oldtitle");
```

the above code produce an null value

Note: oldtitle (Dynamic) attribute binding with KO (Knockout JS) Binding so that i'm not able to getting this, Please guide

Comment: Is there any other element on page with same id but does not has this attribute??

Comment: no it's not, this is for field with validation

Comment: Have to tried any other locator, i.e., id, xpath etc.?

Comment: yes, but i'm not getting (//*[@id='txtEmail']).getattribute("oldtitle")

Comment: So are you saying, that if you use xpath then you are able to get the required attribute in password field but not in email field? If yes, then chances are that the value is being set by javascript, so make sure that you fulfill the condition for error, before accessing the element.

Comment: i used the above for sample id value not for password field

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51100/discussion-between-prabu-and-husam)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. We go in a loop for a maximum of 5 seconds, polling every 500 ms until the apply method returns true.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {    
   public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
      WebElement inputElement= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtRegPassword"));

      if(inputElement.getAttribute("oldtitle") == null) 
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   });
```